# Rails 3.1.3 - backtrace_silencers initializer file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backtrace

I added the following like to the backtrace_silencers initializer file:

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_filter { |line| line.gsub(Rails.root, '') }
```

I get the following error message in my rails server when an exception occurs:

> Error during failsafe response: wrong argument type Pathname (expected
>   Regexp)   .../config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb:2:in `gsub'

Which is odd b/c gsub is used as an example here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_filter { |line| line.gsub(Rails.root.to_s, '') }
```